# return values to a list from a listbox or a button using tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, button, listbox

i'm trying to get the selected values from a list box.
the button that i've created only select and print those items,
but what i really want to do is to return those item into a list and used them in my code
for other purpose.
is there anyway to return a list from a listbox using a buttom
or any other way which i can get the values from the listbox?

```
from tkinter import *
    
    root = Tk()
    root.title("blabla")
    root.geometry("600x650")
    
    Label(text="", width=15).grid(row=0, column=0)
    Label(text="Choose ingredients:", width=15).grid(row=1, column=0)
    ingredients_listbox =Listbox(root, width=20, height=10)
    ingredients_listbox.grid(row=2, column=0)
    
    # create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the listbox
    ingredients_scroll =Scrollbar(command=ingredients_listbox.yview, orient=VERTICAL)
    ingredients_scroll.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ns')
    ingredients_listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=ingredients_scroll.set, selectmode = MULTIPLE)
    
    
    ingredients_list = ["None","eggplant","red_bell_pepper","tomato","onion","garlic","coriander",
                        "zucchini","artichoke","mushrooms","olives","parsley","cauliflower"]
    for item in ingredients_list:
        ingredients_listbox.insert(END,item)
    
    def select_ingredients():
        #print(ingredients_listbox.curselection())
        ingredients_result = []
        for item in ingredients_listbox.curselection():
           ingredients_result.append(str(ingredients_listbox.get(item)))
        print(ingredients_result)
        return ingredients_result
    
    ingredients_button = Button(root, text = "Add ingredients", command = select_ingredients).grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Comment: Simply move `ingredients_result = []` outside `select_ingredients()` and add `ingredients_result.clear()` at the beginning of `select_ingredients()`.  Then you can access `ingredients_result` elsewhere.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks, but it is not working. i get empty list

Comment: It works for me with those changes.  Can you post the updated code?

Comment: @acw1668 maybe i dont understand what you are doing. can you show me your part of the code???

Comment: @acw1668 please !!! i'm trying like 4 hours to return the values. i looked everywhere and didn't find the answer. i'm so frustrated

Comment: Here is the [example](https://pastebin.com/GEN0ugkd) based on your code with the changes I mentioned in my past comment.  I don't know whether it is what you want.